# Could not load master page type

Tags: custom-masterpage

I have created a custom master page with code behind an deployed it as a module in the _catalogs/masterpage folder. The master page should be used by a custom customer pages, but all I get is the following error:

> Could not load type xxx from the assembly xxx

saying that the system could not load type the codebehind class type from the assembly. Does sharepoint have any exclusion/filter in the types it can load?

Here is my module file:

```
//module
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Module Name="MasterPageModule" Url="_catalogs/masterpage" List="116">
         <File Path="Pages\seattle.Master" Url="Pages/seattle.Master" />
    </Module>
</Elements>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Ezzaam. I have edited your message to make it more readable. As a reference, when posting error message, try to use the block quote formatting, not the code one.

Comment: Did you deploy your assembly to GAC? Check GAC if you assembly is deployed properly.

Comment: yeah it's there

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the master page gallery to make sure it is checked in and published?

Comment: yead definitely i did the problem could load the type from assembly